# Use EchoSign Api in C#

Tags: echosign

I need to get the list of document and echosign it in c#. Also I need the Abobe Echosign oauth api to validate the username and password and get the access token key.

Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

There is a another question related to using Adobe Sign api in c#. This might be helpful for you.

[Adobe Sign (echo sign) API sending document using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37166341/adobe-sign-echo-sign-api-sending-document-using-c-sharp)